# Popular Django App Libraries

Tags: python, django

I know there is some really good django app libraries out there (other than the builtin django.contrib.*) but for some reason, my google search abilities are failing me.

I am thinking of one in particular that I cannot remeber the name of for the life of me. I keep wanting to call it pyrex or pixar or something.  Obviously, neither of those are correct.  Any other libraries out there are also appreciated.  I don't really feel like writing a password reset page if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all django apps are registered at the [python package index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).  If you browse the topic hierarchy you'll see that Django is one of the "framework" topics, so that makes it possible to [show all packages which use Django](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&show=all&c=523).

As for the app you are searching for, my guess is you are thinking of [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/)

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/django-basic-apps/ ?

also:

http://code.google.com/p/django-profile/

and

http://code.google.com/p/django-registration/

I have found useful.

Comment: Looks promising! I still know there is another one out there (not for just authentication).  It has a lot of hype right now.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) to be a great place to start [searching for Django apps and libraries](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=django).

- search: [django-pi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=django-pi&submit=search)
- search: [django-py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=django-py&submit=search)

Maybe you were looking for [django-piston](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-piston/0.2.2)?